# Apache equivalent of runserver view

Tags: python, apache

Django provides a runserver that prints out the requests in near-real time in the cli. How would I print out all requests for a website that runs on apache/wsgi?

Answer (score 2):

You would run `tail -F` on the web server's logs, or you would run the web server in the foreground via `httpd -X`.

Comment: How would I find where the web server's logs are? (Amazon EC2 instance.) There are tons of log files here...

Comment: You'd have to check the configuration. But they're usually under `/var/log`.